# Python unicodecsv.writer rewriting all previous rows each time a new row is written

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm parsing data from several excel files, transforming them, and writing them to a single csv file. I was able to get it to work. However, I decided to break the parts into functions and run the script by calling each function sequentially.

After making this change, the writer portion of the script is looping somehow and now writes the following:
header_row, data_row1, header_row, data_row1, data_row2, header_row ...

Below is the print function where the problem is occuring. I've confirmed that the data in the DictList2 is correctly formed and that [headers] is accurate.

```
def PrintProcess2(directory2):
    with open(directory2 + "participant list.csv", 'wb') as f:
        headers = sorted([k for k, v in DictList2[0].items()])
        csv_data = [headers]
        for d in DictList2:
            csv_data.append([d[h] for h in headers])

            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(csv_data)
```

The code in this function is identical to the version without functions, and that one writes the data correctly. I'm completely stumped at this point. Can someone help?

Comment: Removed irrelevant `xlrd` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't create a new csv.writer instance each time around the loop.
2. Your main problem is that you are appending rows to csv_data then using writerows ... try something like the following:

   `def PrintProcess2(directory2):
       with open(directory2 + "participant list.csv", 'wb') as f:
           writer = csv.writer(f)
           headers = sorted([k for k, v in DictList2[0].items()])
           writer.writerow(headers)
           for d in DictList2:
               writer.writerow([d[h] for h in headers])`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!